# transposing a dataframe and dealing with column names

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I have dataframe created by reading in a csv. I want to transpose the Dataframe so that the timestamps become column and the ids (numbers starting with 7) become rows. In the process I change the DateTime column name to be 'sensor_id' as I want this to be the name of the column containing the ids once the transpose has taken place. On the face of it the transpose function works

However 'sensor_id' is still linked to the timestamps. The transposed dataframe does not recognize sensor_id as the name of the column that now holds the ids

In fact the column now holding the ids does not seem to be accessible. If I try to access the column at index 0 --  print(df.iloc[2, 0]) I get the value 0.00006 rather than 763753. 
[image]
Is it possible to act on the transposed ids as if it was a column?

Comment: Could you give the dataframe (or an extract of it) as copyable **text**? Or even better, could you give an extract of the csv file as text (because a csv file is a text file) and the code that you are currently using to load and transform the data?

Comment: Serge. Thanks for your reply. new to this so will look into how to attach or provide the things you mention. But may have solved it for my humble purposes. I tried inserting a new column to the df -> df.insert(0, 'sensor_id', df.index). It seems to have done the trick. I needed that column to then use the melt function on my df.. thanks

Comment: That's the reason why I am asking for text data. It is easier to add to the question: just edit the question, add the text data and format is as code (**not** snippet). Maybe for next question :-)